# Handling colored bash prompt

Tags: regex, linux, terminal, prompt, ansi-escape

I have an adapter code which executes some specific commands on a Linux machine via SSH. It executes commands and handles the output of each command in a specified manner.

The issue being faced is very straightforward.

I am connecting to a Bash prompt that uses colors. Here are the details of the PS1 variable:

```
PS1="\[\033[1;34m\][\$(date +%H%M)][\u@\h:\w]$\[^[[0m}\]"
```

The code uses regex which decides a valid terminal first and then proceeds with the commands.

For example, `.*\$` is considered valid

I can't seem to handle `[^[[0m}` properly and code is not able to identify the terminal as a valid one. If I remove it from PS1 variable, things work fine.

Can anyone please suggest what regular expressions might be entered so that the code takes it as a valid terminal?

Comment: Would it be possible to use extended regexes? I hate having to escape meta characters...

Comment: I am not really sure.May be i can. And yeah i am having no clue how to escape that. Any clue to move forward?

Comment: Wait, is PS1 a regex or not? Can you provide some more code?

Comment: yes it is .Unfortunately that is all I have at the moment :/. If I can change the code , could have tried more things

Comment: You may want to try `PS1=\[\e[0;37m\]\D{%R}\[\e[1;34m\] \h:\w> \[\e[0m\]` which appears similar. e.g. `02:16 alchemy:~/dev/src-c/tmp/tst> `

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the PS1 variable you provided above is broken.

I ran the following experiment in my terminal window:

```
[guest@localhost ~] $ export PS1="\\[\033[1;34m\\][\$(date +%H%M)][\u@\h:\w]$\\[^[[0m}\\]"

[2137][guest@localhost:~]$^[[0m}
```

As you can see `^[[0m}` is not interpreted properly. I assume it is the end of the color in the prompt. I think it should be `\\[\033[0m\\]`.

Here is the whole PS1 variable:

```
PS1="\\[\033[1;34m\\][\$(date +%H%M)][\u@\h:\w]$\\[\033[0m\\]"
```

After testing it you get this:

```
[2137][guest@localhost:~]$^[[0m}export PS1="\\[\033[1;34m\\][\$(date +%H%M)][\u@\h:\w]$\\[\033[0m\\]"

[2139][guest@localhost:~]$
```